# How to reuse existing C# code in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a C# network protocol library (about 5000 LOC) which I want to reuse in an android app. The protocol is likely to change in the future.

What is a good way to do this?

- Port the library to Java/Android?
- Use some sort of C# to Java converter like [this](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html). Build a Java library with the source and use it in my Android app?
- Build a android service with Xamarin.Android (monodroid) and write a native Android app which uses this service?
- other options?!

Comment: Well that's one of the benefit of using MonoDroid, you can integrate existing .NET code (given it's supported on Mono and surfaced in MonoDroid). I've done this in the past pretty successfully using MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make an Android app and using Java isn't a requirement, Xamarin.Android is a very good solution. The way you build the app is pretty much the same as you would with Java. You still have resource files and axml files, etc. The main difference is that you use C# instead of Android.

There has also been some anecdotes that the .NET VM runs faster than Android's Dalvik JVM. So it is possible that your C# code will run faster than a Java port.

The Alpha Channel of Xamarin Studio has initial support for PCLs so if you have your library as a PCL already it may turn out to very easy to just plug it in.

You may want to check out this discussion to get a sense of Pros and Cons of C# vs. Java:
[MonoDroid VS Java in android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951673/monodroid-vs-java-in-android-development?rq=1)

You can also use this website to scan your lib to see how mobile friendly it is:
http://scan.xamarin.com/